# Error while reading json from pdf file using iText

Tags: android, json, itext, gson

I have been trying to read JSON from pdf file. I am able to write the JSON string into pdf but when I read the pdf I am getting the error as below.

> Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated
>   object at line 60 column 3 path $.All_Routes[0].route_data

I printed the JSON before writing into a file and validate it online using JSON validator and it's **a valid JSON** but after I **write** to pdf, it becomes **invalid**. I just copied JSON from pdf and validated it online but it was not validated and giving errors.

Here is the code to write JSON to pdf file.

```
try {
    File file = AppUtils.createFile(".pdf");
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    document.addCreationDate();
    document.addAuthor("Me");
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();

    String jsonBody = new Gson().toJson(backUpModel);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(jsonBody);
    String prettyJsonBody = gson.toJson(jsonElement);

    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Input Json: " + prettyJsonBody);
    document.add(new Paragraph(prettyJsonBody));
    document.close();

    //Toast.makeText(BackUp.this, "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the code to read the PDF file.

```
try {
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Constants.TAG);
    String filePath = exportDir.getPath() + File.separator + getFileName(fileUri);
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
    int numberOfPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, i));
    }
    pdfReader.close();
    String jsonBody = stringBuilder.toString();
    BackUpModel backUpModel = new Gson().fromJson(jsonBody, BackUpModel.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anybody suggest me possible solutions to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: *"I have been trying to read JSON from pdf file"* - how did you try? When you compare that read text to the original json, how do they differ?

Comment: @mkl You can get both the JSON from the above links. You can validate or compare it using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @mkl i have added the code to read the JSON from PDF file.

Comment: Your problem is line breaks and extra space that `new Paragraph():` is adding.
`new Paragraph()` is an abstraction that handle things like space, paragraph etc by it self. you need to do this manually to write perfect `JSON`

Comment: *"You can get both the JSON from the above links"* - the second link opens a pdf. What does the extracted text from that pdf look like? How does it differ from the original? I'm currently on a smart phone only and cannot execute your text extraction code (which by the way looks reasonable).

Comment: That being said, does the text have to be put into the pdf like that? Using a multi line text form field would allow retrieval of a more correct value...

Comment: @mkl as Ashwini Violet mentioned. It's an issue of a line break. If I make 'route_data' string into one line it works fine but I don't know how it will be done programmatically.

Comment: How about removing line breaks in the stringBuilder, i.e. replacing them with empty strings?

Comment: That being said, probably some line breaks occurred where the original json contained a space, and those spaces may be lost in this whole process. Because of that my question whether am alternative approach would work, too...

Comment: @Hitendra Please have a look here, maybe it can help you, it showing different ways to write other then `Paragraph` object  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/chunk.html

Comment: @AshwiniViolet let me try

Comment: @AshwiniViolet it's not working as it's overlapping the text in pdf and gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the input json with the output it becomes clear that you cannot faithfully extract the json from the PDFs as generated by your current code.

The problems occur where the rendering of the string to PDF adds line breaks to prevent the text from running into the margin. Each line break in the result may either have already been in the input string or may have been introduced by iText, and in general it is not recognizable which is the case.

If iText broke the line at a whitespace or punctuation (colon, comma, bracket) *outside* a name or value, these extra line breaks don't change the meaning of the json object, but line breaks inside names and values are a different story.

Even if we could assume that there aren't any line breaks in the names or values (actually there are line breaks in values in the json you shared, but those line breaks might have crept in due to the way you shared it) and, therefore, we could simply remove them, some of those line breaks have been applied where there was a space in the original value and others are not. Where a line is broken at a space, that space is dropped and does not appear anymore in the final output. And again, in general it is not recognizable which is the case with only the extracted output at hand.

Thus, faithful extraction is not possible.

---

As a consequence, you have to change the way you embed the json in the PDF. As you did not mention why you do this at all and what alternative options you have, I cannot give a final proposal, merely present some options which may or may not be compatible with your requirements:

- Embed the json not as regular, static page content but as value of a multi-line form text field. Values in form fields can faithfully be extracted from a PDF.
- In addition to the visible json in the page content, also embed the json in a private stream object in the PDF; you can then faithfully extract the json from that stream object.
- Use a font size so small that no line breaks are added by iText during rendering. (The result most likely will be much too small for reading without zooming in, though.)
- Render the json manually (using low level iText APIs) and somehow mark your added line breaks and dropped spaces. During extraction you have to react to those markers.

---

For example, to implement option 1, *embedding the json as value of a multi-line form text field*, one simply adds it like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
document.addCreationDate();
document.addAuthor("Me");
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(jsonPdfFile));
document.open();
pdfWriter.getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true);
TextField textField = new TextField(pdfWriter, document.getPageSize(), "json");
textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.READ_ONLY);
PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
field.setValueAsString(originalJson);
pdfWriter.addAnnotation(field);
document.close();
```

and extracts it again like this:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(jsonPdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
String jsonBody = pdfReader.getAcroFields().getField("json");
pdfReader.close();
```

*([ExtractJson](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/ExtractJson.java#L106) test `testJsonToPdfToJsonFormField`)*

<sub>*I'm using the current iText 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT development branch. The code should work with any 5.5.x version, though.*</sub>

Comment: can you explain how can i do this?
Embed the json not as regular, static page content but as value of a multi-line form text field. Values in form fields can faithfully be extracted from a PDF.

Comment: *"can you explain ..."* - I've added an example to my answer.